# MICROPHONE - How is this PIN actually called?

Tags: microphone, setup, microphone-positioning

I have a Yeti Blue mic that I am now setting up. I got the 3/8 to 5/8 thread adapter, but the mic is just too high up the horizontal boom arm, so I actually wanted to drop it down a bit.

I was thinking to get a longer "PIN" that the 3/8 adapter feeds into, but I have NO IDEA how that thing is called. Spent some time researching, but I must not be using the right term for it.

Here is the image:

[image: Mic Pin]

Comment: A picture might be worth 1000 words for this one. Often the trick is to just invert the mic, but I can't see how you have it set up or which bit you mean.

Comment: Here is the image, https://www.screencast.com/t/vWfUGqSz

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what that is, nor how it would fit into your setup - we're missing the big picture of exactly what you're trying to achieve... we're only getting what you think you need to do to achieve it.

Comment: so, this is the microphone you're talking about? https://www.bluedesigns.com/products/yeti/  And you've replaced the stand with a boom? A photo of your mic in its assembled state would help.